# Question about determinig types of surfaces?

Tags: analytic-geometry, surfaces

$$x^2 +y^2 +z^2 +2x +1=0$$

This is an equation for dot if we are talking about surfaces, right?
It is not an ellipsoid.

Comment: This is a single point $(-1,0,0)$, as 

$$(x+1)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the equation of a point:
$$(x + 1)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0$$
has only one solution $(-1, 0, 0)$.

Is it an ellipsoid? That comes down to your definition of an ellipsoid.  It's certainly an edge case.  This definition of an [Ellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) doesn't allow it.